# Converter SQL para Eloquent do Laraval 5

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel-5

Estou tentando transformar esse SQL do postgres abaixo para o eloquent no laraval alguem tem uma ideia de como ficaria?

```
select 
  g.id as group_id,
  max(g.name) as name,
  max(g.created_at) as created_at,
  count(ag.asset_id) as veichele
from "groups" g left join assets_groups ag on g.id = ag.group_id 
group by g.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o seu `model` [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) for com o nome `Groups` é basicamente:

```
$select = 'groups.id as group_id, max(groups.name) as name,';
$select .= 'max(groups.created_at) as created_at,';
$select .= 'count(assets_groups.asset_id) as veichele';

$result = Groups::groupBy('groups.id')
      ->leftJoin('assets_groups', 'assets_groups.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
      ->selectRaw($select);
```

essa seria a construção da [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries).